Bondage Discipline: =, <-, ->
These all mean the same (but the syntactic options seem a little quirky):
let x       = <expr> in ...
let (x)     = <expr> in ...
let (((x))) = <expr> in ...      -- any depth of nesting allowed

These mean the same (but the syntactic options seem hard to explain):
let f x y       = <expr> in ...
let (f x) y     = <expr> in ...
let (((f x))) y = <expr> in ...  -- any depth of nesting allowed
-- let (f x y)  = <expr> in ...  -- rejected `Parse error in pattern: f`

The declaration is in the land of lambda calculus binding: within the ..., substitute for x the RHS <expr> (the function form is effectively let f = \x y -> <expr> in ...).
let Just z       = <expr> in ...
let (Just z)     = <expr> in ...
let (((Just z))) = <expr> in ...  -- any depth of nesting allowed

This seems not in the land of lambda calculus: there's no expression such that I can substitute it for z in .... OTOH I suppose this is lazy: if evaluating <expr> would fail to match (Just z), nothing gets upset until/unless you try to use z.
Other places in Haskell syntax kinda acknowledges this:

List comprehensions use <- to show there's work to do on RHS of <- to make a binding;

Monads (do notation's <-) likewise;

Guards are explicitly designed to follow the model of List comprehensions:
  f x | [y] <- x
      , y > 3
      , Just z <- h y
      , let y2 = y * 2
      = ...



The <- there says there's work to do: evaluate RHS; try to bind to LHS pattern; if that fails, abandon this equation for f, move on to try the next. Whereas the let is lazy.
Haskell also has an arrow -> facing the other way, used in case branches and lambda expressions (example \(Just x) -> ...), meaning roughly: try to bind the scrutinee to the pattern, if you succeed, carry on with the RHS; if not, for a case move on to try the next branch, for a lambda, fail.
Then please explain/what is the mental model I should use for:

View patterns length (view -> Cons x xs) = 1 + length xs -- why is the pattern-to-bind on RHS?
pattern synonym declarations (unidirectional form) pattern Head x <- x:xs. This doesn't mean sth like evaluate the RHS, try to bind the result to LHS. (It means more like: at a usage site where Head z appears, substitute variable name x -> z in RHS, giving z:xs.)

Addit:
"How do you feel about the mental model 'memorize it'?" asks one of the comments (and another comment in same vein).
I feel that if I wanted icky ad-hoc syntax with all sorts of strange symbols, there's plenty other languages could give me that.
Specifically, ViewPatterns syntax is ghastly. Furthermore there was an alternative proposed at the time with much more Haskell-like elegant syntax, and just the same functionality. So there isn't a "complicated thing they translate to", rather they turn a reasonably Haskell-aligned semantics into syntactic obfuscation.
For PatternSynonyms, there was a debate at the time as to which direction the arrow should point. I could find no documented rationale for the decision (coin toss?); so I see no necessary reason for the obfuscation.
And in general my title is hinting GHC is turning Haskell into a language with same-as-the-rest mental overhead to follow. That is, unless someone here can explain how the syntactic choices relate back to the elegant core Haskell used to have.
Addit 2: ViewPattern syntax considered "ghastly"

-> in Haskell lambda/case means if match pattern to left then ...
The way to bind names to the result of a calculation in Haskell is on the left: pattern <- expr or = expr; in C is = expr; in Algol family in general is := expr. (There's a few stack-based languages go -> var; => var -- meaning take the value off the top of the stack, store in var.)
It's not so much the argument is "unnamed" (as an answer puts it), as that it's invisible. I hate anything imaginary like that in any language.
Types: consider


    parsePacket (bits 3 -> Just (n, (bits n -> Just (val, bs)))) = ...



So the type of that argument expression is a Maybe something? No.
There's a -> so it's some sort of function type? No.
It's bare ByteString. Does that type have constructor Just? No.
Just no. Don't expect to be able to read such an expression and have a fair guess at its type. Just not Haskell.


Basically, f x y is itself not a pattern, but a name f and a pair of patterns x and y. The parser has to be free to "peel off" the individual patterns from the right so that it can transform, for example, let f x y = ... into let f x = case y of ....

How do you feel about the mental model "memorize it"? I'm not sure there's a much more succinct explanation than that, really.

Haskell syntax is simply richer than raw lambda calculus. It has a lot more concepts (which is natural, as the original lambda calculus was deliberately designed as a minimal model of computation - to be easy to prove things about, rather than easy to express things with), which all need strict syntactic forms. Haskell is designed to be relatively easy to understand in terms of how it would translate to lambda calculus, but some of the translation is very straightforward and some of it is "memorise these symbols and patterns; here's a complicated thing they translate to".

I don't know if this is a good answer to your question, but it seems like your concern about the use of arrows in Haskell syntax is the main part of your question, and I can at least tell you how I think about them.
On arrows
I have always read the <- arrow as roughly hinting "comes from", and correspondingly -> as roughly indicating "goes to". The precise way in which the left side "comes from" or "goes to" the right side is different in different syntactic features that use the arrow, of course; there is always some level at which language features have to be simply memorised.
So in case blocks case mx of Just x -> x + 1, the case examination maps patterns to results; Just x "goes to" x + 1.
In list comprehensions [ x + 1 | x <- xs ], the variable x "comes from" the list xs. Same for monadic binds in do block syntax.
In pattern guards, f x | [y] <- x = ..., we're defining y as "coming from" x via the pattern [y]
In lambda syntax \x -> x + 1, we're writing a function literal that maps argument values x to results x + 1; x "goes to" x + 1.
And of course I read type expressions like Int -> Char -> Bool as "Int goes to Char goes to Bool" (with implied right associativity, of course).
Finally, to view patterns
So with that interpretation, view pattern syntax seems to make reasonable sense to me.
length (view -> Cons x xs) = 1 + length xs

To me this reads as: apply the function view to the unnamed argument of length, and the result of that application "goes to" the pattern Cons x xs to bind variable names for use in the RHS. (And for what it's worth, I learned Haskell before view patterns existed, and still use them only rarely; my "mental model" of how to read the arrows was not formed by view patterns)
The syntax that you prefer, judging by your link, would be:
length (a | Cons x xs <- view a) = 1 + length xs

I can see some appeal to this syntax as being perhaps a little clearer (at the cost of being a little more verbose; we had to name the argument and write out the expression being matched in full). But I would still regard the arrow as hinting at almost exactly the same interpretation; regardless of whether it's a left arrow or a right arrow, it's still pointing from a computation to a pattern that will be matched to the result of that computation; I don't see why one is "ghastly" and the other is "elegant".
Reading the proposal you linked I realised that it isn't really a syntax for view patterns specifically at all, rather it's essentially about making the syntax used for guards (including pattern guards) usable inside patterns. In my opinion that's actually it's biggest weakness; it doesn't really give you anything over just using guards, it just lets you write the pieces in a different order. We could just as well have written it like this (and even saved a pair of parentheses):
length a
 | Cons x xs <- view x = 1 + length xs

The view pattern syntax that was chosen gives you shorthand notation for sort of "composing" a pattern and a function application; without that feature you can get exactly the same functionality by just writing a pattern guard as above (and in fact that's probably what I would usually do, since I almost never think to use view patterns). I can see why people would want to complicate the language a little to have that shorthand.
The alternative proposal doesn't address the desire for shorthand; if view patterns don't really provide any functionality, just a more concise way to write something that could otherwise be written in a slightly longer and more complex fashion with pattern guards, I don't see as much motivation for merely getting a different way of writing the pattern guard that has exactly the same "moving parts". The alternative proposal seems to have much more merit as an argument to not bother implementing view patterns than as a suggestion for syntax to actually implement, in my opinion.
Pattern synonyms
I love pattern synonyms as a feature, but I must admit I am always confused by the syntax for pattern synonyms other than simple bidirectional ones. I have to look it up every time.

pattern synonym declarations (unidirectional form) pattern Head x <- x:xs. This doesn't mean sth like evaluate the RHS, try to bind the result to LHS. (It means more like: at a usage site where Head z appears, substitute variable name x -> z in RHS, giving z:xs.)

Hmm. I am a little confused by what you're confused by, here. My mental model for what pattern Head x <- x:xs means is: when I write a pattern like Head z, the compiler should first match the pattern x:xs, and then take the value corresponding to x from the RHS to use as the definition of my variable z. So I do sortof think of it as "evaluating the RHS pattern and then using that to bind the variables on the LHS".
Where I get confused is whether that should be "comes from" or "goes to". One way to think about it is that a pattern synonym is "mapping patterns"; I write Head x and it gets transformed into x:xs (I suppose that's the interpretation you're describing above). That interpretation suggests a right arrow. But another way to think about it is that Head is a "virtual constructor", whose fields "come from" the real underlying constructor when we pattern match on it. That interpretation suggests a left arrow.
Ultimately I don't think there was a great choice available here. I think either direction of arrow is quite justifiable. But if the final syntax had been pattern Head x -> x:xs I don't think it would stop me from getting the syntax confused, and it would reinforce the "mapping patterns" interpretation, which I think is less helpful - it suggests that the variable bindings in scope when I use Head should be those on the RHS, as it replaces the pattern I wrote, but of course that doesn't make sense. And certainly when we consider explicitly bidirectional patterns where one of the two definitions is used as a function, the "goes to" interpretation is much more applicable to the function clause, so it would be very confusing to use it for the pattern-matching clause. Perhaps I would have preferred a slightly more verbose syntax with some keywords or a new symbol; I'm not sure. I can't think of any concrete suggestion that I like more than the real syntax.

Thank you for your comprehensive and considered answer. I'll take some time working through it. I'll add a bit more explanation to the q re the "ghastly". With the 'goes to' <- 'comes from', my mental model in Haskell (and for C, ALGOL, Fortran, Lisp SETQ, ...) is 'goes to' the left. (I read <- as 'gets'.)

" pattern guards [<-] ... much more similar to ordinary let or top-level binding" I think not, because let etc are lazy. Its meaning is more 'arrowy' in the same way as case ->s: if you can't match the pattern, abandon this branch, try the next.

@AntC Yeah, that's a very good point. Although the arrow in case syntax isn't for that part (it points from a pattern to the result expression, rather than from the thing being analysed to the pattern), so it's not similar to that arrow, even though it's similar to case analysis. I think I was comparing the pattern guard arrow to the arrow used do bindings (or list comprehension), and feeling like pattern guard matching is more similar to let than it is to those. But now that you've made me think, probably not the best way to think about it. Hmm.


[o.p. Addit] For PatternSynonyms, there was a debate at the time as to which direction the arrow should point.


[@Ben] I am a little confused by what you're confused by, here. ... Where I get confused is whether that should be "comes from" or "goes to".

Note that for a PatternGuard (like | Just z <- h y), there's no variables in common (but the two sides must be at same type): the target pattern decomposes the passed value and binds to the vars structurally/by position.

For a fully bidirectional PattSyn equation (like pattern Maybe t     = App "Maybe" [t]), the two sides must have exactly the same-named free vars, and the correspondence is by name/the PattSyn constructor doesn't necessarily take the same number of args/is not the same structure as the data constructor.
For the underneath lines of an explicitly bidirectional (the same as with ordinary function equations like const x y = x) the free vars on RHS must be a subset of those on the left.
For the top/only line of an explicitly bidirectional (like pattern Head x <- x:xs), the free vars on RHS must be a superset of those on the left.

All the beginner-level PattSyn declarations are fully bidirectional, so you can get a long way by reading those equations left-to-right like function equations. I had been thinking that when the PattSyn is used in matcher position, substitute its actual arguments into the RHS like you would with a function call; except don't 'apply' the data constructor, merely leave that as a pattern. IOW I was thinking of it as some variety of macro expansion. But that mental model breaks down where there's free vars on RHS not appearing on LHS.
To the paper, §5, after Point 5.

... it is worth noting that the semantics of matching a pattern synonym is subtly different from macro-substitution. Consider: ...
[gnarly example revealing different behaviour where one of the values inside a structure is bottom]



(a) Match the value v against p.


Where p is the RHS pattern given from the PattSyn, using the var names as given in that decl. So this is a structural match by position, as with a <- guard. At this stage there's no looking at the var names actually appearing at the call site.
If that match succeeds, then map each varname xi from p to param position in the PattSyn decl to corresponding position pattern pi at the call site. "map"? -- well, also match because those are patterns at the call site, which might not be as simple as a bare var, so the map-match might fail.
So we might express this two-step match-map-match like
pattern Head x <~~ x: xs <- ('a': 'b': [])

in which "ab" is the value v we're binding to at the match site, and <~~ is map-match by name-position. Note the matcher usage site might look like
foo :: [Maybe a]    -> ...
foo (Head (Just y1)) = ...
foo ...              = ...

So call foo [Nothing, Just 'b'] will fail to match that first equation for foo. Calling foo [Just 'a', Just 'b'] binds 'a' to y1 on RHS of foo, going via x1 (its position) from the PattSyn decl, but x1 is not in scope on RHS of foo. Compare
pattern Head21 x2 x1 = x1: x2: xs



(c) ... (The xi are not bound; they remain local to the pattern synonym declaration.)


Hmm. ... then have I convinced myself a single <- expresses all that not very guard-like binding?
